# How can I update a many to many field in Django

Tags: python, html, django

**I am trying to update a many to many field button when a user clicks a button**

The Payment model is to allow users to submit their receipts to be reimbursed. Each Payment has a "many to many" field named status. Currently, there are only two statuses a payment can have "complete" or "incomplete". When a user submits a payment the default is incomplete, and when the company issues a check to reimburse the user, the company needs to be able to click a button that will update the payment to 'complete'.

To get a better idea of what this looks like, the HTML page looks like this.
[The Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJLJc.png)

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Status(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.type}'

class Payment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    receipt_img = models.FileField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='receipt_pics')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(Status)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} Contribution'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contrib-home')
```

**The button that sends the request in payment_detail.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'update-status' operation='complete' pk=object.id %}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Complete</button>
</a>
```

**The urls.py**

```
path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.update_status, name='update-status')
```

**The views.py**

```
class PaymentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Payment
    template_name = 'financial/payment_detail.html'


def update_status(request, operation, pk):
    payment = Payment.objects.get(id=pk)
    if operation == 'complete':
        print("Many to many field print")
        payment.status.first().type = 'complete'
        payment.save()
        return redirect('payment-detail', pk=pk)
    return redirect('payment-detail', pk=pk)
```

I have tried multiple solutions from other posts but I keep getting many errors like Cannot edit many to many fields. Any insight or help would be very helpful because there doesn't seem to be much on the internet for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the Status object not the payment object.

```
def update_status(request, operation, pk):
    payment = Payment.objects.get(id=pk)
    if operation == 'complete':
        print("Many to many field print")
        status = payment.status.first()
        status.type = 'complete'
        status.save()
        return redirect('payment-detail', pk=pk)
    return redirect('payment-detail', pk=pk)
```

Also if you want to update all status objects related to payment this would also work `payment.status.all().update(type='complete')`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this solution did not work. I ran the code and instead of changing that individual payment's status it changes the actual status type in the DB so the result is all payments with the status incomplete will now have complete.

Comment: @DanielGrinevich You were changing it in your question though? You don't appear to have any other attribute like status in your `Payment` model? It only has a `ManytoMany` field with the status model for some reason? Do you have something like various status instances already made and want to save to that?

Comment: I only want the payment that corresponds to the private key status to change. So the way the table is set up there is a Payment table and each Payment has a pk. There is a Status table, where which each status has a id corresponded to it. So status id 2 = incomplete and status id 3 = complete. There is a table in between that uses the payment PK and the Status ID to map the payment to the status. Your solution changed the actual status id so each status id 2 = incomplete changed to complete, but I only want that one payment to change its status. Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: @DanielGrinevich Can each payment have multiple statuses? If not why have you used a ManyToMany Field?

Comment: The idea was to have payments have multiple statuses like incomplete with other statuses that could be like pending transfer, but I think it would be easier just to make more variables without many too many. (simpler to code)